# how to use hlookup in Excel VBA with a range of data from another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use the `HLookUp Function`, but the range is from another sheet and I can't get it right.

```
Sub P()

Dim mes As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim valor As Double
Dim bobes As Range
bobes = Worksheets("Cash Cost EP").Range("C3:S10")

i = 4
Do Until Cells(2, i) = ""
    mes = Cells(2, i)
    mes = Right(Cells(2, i), 2)
    If mes = "01" Then
        mes = "Enero"
    ElseIf mes = "02" Then
        mes = "Febrero"
    ElseIf mes = "03" Then
        mes = "Marzo"
    ElseIf mes = "04" Then
        mes = "Abril"
    ElseIf mes = "05" Then
        mes = "Mayo"
    ElseIf mes = "06" Then
        mes = "Junio"
    ElseIf mes = "07" Then
        mes = "Julio"
    ElseIf mes = "08" Then
        mes = "Agosto"
    ElseIf mes = "09" Then
        mes = "Setiembre"
    ElseIf mes = "10" Then
        mes = "Octubre"
    ElseIf mes = "11" Then
        mes = "Noviembre"
    ElseIf mes = "12" Then
        mes = Diciembre
    End If
    Sheets("resumen").Range("d17").Value = "= HLookup(mes, bobes, 3, 0)"
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

When I run the code, it doesn't work the way I want it to.
Pleas help, I want to get the value of the `Hlookup` in cell `D17`.

Comment: your `Do Until Cells(2, i) = ""` for each `i` rewrites formula in `Sheets("resumen").Range("d17")`? Is it what you're going to achive? Or maybe you need to change address of `Range("d17")` for each `i`?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear as 'doesn't work the way I want it to' is a little vague as to what the problem is. I would guess that you need to change the line below to:

`Sheets("resumen").Range("d17").Value = "=HLOOKUP(" & Chr(34) & mes & Chr(34) _
    & ",'" & bobes.Parent.Name & "'!" & bobes.Address & ",3,0)"`

So that you pass the value of `mes` (including double quotes) rather than the text 'mes' to the function and also identify the worksheet and range address of the `bobes` range.